# certbot option to _display_ configs (specifically currently-registered email address)

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

Does anyone know of an option with `certbot` (a.k.a. `letsencrypt`) to *show* the current configuration options? I know one can specify the config file (`--config`) and specify the registered email address (`-m`), but I'd like to inspect (in an automated way) the *existing* configuration values prior to executing a `certbot` command. I also know that I can inspect the canonical config file, but it's nice to have the program report exactly how it sees the config options (after applying things like default logic) as opposed to making assumptions about canonical file locations and reading those files separately.

So far the only robust method I've thought of is to run a verbose dry-run (`-vvv --dry-run`) and parse those results, but that seems pretty flaky :-/.

Answer (score 0):

Since version [1.23](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/releases/tag/v1.23.0) there is a new subcommand to show details:

```
certbot show_account
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71951868/4970442).